# Element in col shifts slightly when element in adjacent column is toggled

Tags: html, css, containers

Currently working on a weather app using bootstrap, and within one row I have two columns: one side shows the temperature, which can be toggled between C and F, and the other shows other basic weather information (right now I just have a basic weather description). But when I toggle the temperature between C and F, the differences in width of those two letters appears to push the weather info slightly to the left or right.

I've tried applying position:absolute/relative and floats to both elements, but can't seem to fix the problem. Any help would be appreciated!

All my code is in Codepen: https://codepen.io/alissaw/pen/pppzwd but here is the element-specific code isolated (#weatherdata is the element that's shifting):

```
   <body>
  <div>
    <h1 id = "location">
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="loader"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label class="switch">
          <input type="checkbox">
          <div class="slider">
          </div>
          <div class="text"></div>
        </label>
        <p id="temp"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2 id="weatherData">
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

--- CSS ---
body{
  background-color: #4FCCFF;
  text-align: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.container{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#location{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-weight: 200;
}
#temp{
      font-size: 100px;
      font-family: Raleway;
      font-weight: 250;
      float: left;
      color: white;
    }

#weatherData{
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-weight: 200;
  margin-top: 5%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in your codepen I noticed that you used bootstrap classes but did not add in the bootstrap CSS file. I added the CSS file in and it seemed to work just fine without the shifting.

From the settings try adding in the bootstrap file:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.css